# Undefined Class/Module when Serializing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, eager-loading

I am storing an array of typed objects in an ActiveRecord model like:

```
class Store::Bin < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :items, Array
end

class Store::Item
   include Virtus.model
   attribute :name, String
   ...
end
```

When I make a code change in `development` mode and refresh my browser, I get an `undefined class/module Store::Item` exception.

It seems like something is getting crossed up with the class loading.  All files are in the `app/models/store/...` directory, properly named w/r to their camelcase name.

The same issue happens when using the rails console.  `reload!` does not fix the issue in the console; instead I have to exit and restart the console.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a type to the array seemed to solve the problem.... but caused an issue with the associated FactoryGirl factory.

```
class Store::Bin < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :items, Array[Store::Item]
end
```

UPDATE: the real issue was that when a code change is made to store/bin.rb, that class gets auto-loaded, but the auto loader had no idea that Store::Item was a dependency.

THE REAL FIX:  Declare the required dependency using [require_dependency](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/Loadable/require_dependency)

```
require_dependency "store/item"
class Store::Bin < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :items, Array
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the `::` operator when defining classes because of Rails autoload problems. Instead, try

```
module Store
  class Item
     # ...
  end
end
```

When you're not sure what's going on you can use [Module.nesting](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html) to figure out how Rails interprets the hierarchy.

Comment: Unfortunately specifying the module separately did not solve my issue because it was related to the autoloader not seeing the requirement to the serialized class:  Store::Item